# Why do I need a Virtual Private Server(VPS)?

Tags: python, web, flask

I have Linux Ubuntu installed and I want to code my Flask app in Linux only.But certain tutorials are coding the web app in a VPS.Why do I need a VPS?Can't I build my web app locally and directly host my site on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host your application in any form you like.

VPS are an abstraction of a machine, giving you all the resources your application would need often at a fraction of the price required to get a physical server just for you. So it may be a good idea to use a VPS for the development and first phase in the life of your website.

You may also directly choose to deploy your website in one of the many cloud providers. Often they will not charge you until you start hitting a certain amount of resource utilization. So that may also be a cost saver.

You can find some additional info about the benefits of VPS [here](http://www.webhostinghub.com/web-hosting-guide/the-pros-and-cons-of-vps-web-hosting).

**Note I am not associated with the website in any way**, I just found it to be quite thorough in talking about VPS.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

I was reading this link.Can I use the same step to develop my web app locally on my computer?

Comment: yes, but instead of starting the server on the virtual host, start it on your localhost